# TeamBuild: How to create a bug on a partially successful build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2008 and writing my builds using the built-in TeamBuild.  I have the build set up in such a way that it will create a work item of type Bug upon failure, and will also create a bug upon unit test failure.  However; today our build partially succeeded due to the fact that an exec task kicked off an executable which had a return code that was not 0.

My question then; is there some way to determine a partial succession of a build and create a bug work item based on that detection?

A snippet from the build .proj file in which I create a bug based on a failed unit test run:

```
<Target Name="AfterTest">
<!-- Refresh the build properties. -->
<GetBuildProperties TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
                    BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
                    Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'true' ">
  <Output TaskParameter="TestSuccess" PropertyName="TestSuccess" />
</GetBuildProperties>

<!-- Set CompilationStatus to Failed if TestSuccess is false. -->
<SetBuildProperties TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
                    BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
                    CompilationStatus="Failed"
                    Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'true' and '$(TestSuccess)' != 'true' ">
</SetBuildProperties>

<CreateNewWorkItem BuildNumber="$(BuildNumber)"
                   BuildURi="$(BuildURI)"
                   Description="A failed test run caused the CreateNewWorkItem task created this bug. $(BuildlogText)"
                   TeamProject="$(TeamProject)"
                   TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
                   Title="Unit Test Failure in $(BuildNumber)"
                   WorkItemFieldValues="$(WorkItemFieldValues)"
                   WorkItemType="Bug"
                   Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'true' and '$(TestSuccess)' != 'true' ">
</CreateNewWorkItem>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check for the error in another part of the build life cycle like

```
AfterDropBuild
```

You find the different targets to extend [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not as much confused on where in the life cycle to check for the error, rather HOW to check for "Partially Successful".